# How to add take styles from a less file instead of css in react-day-picker?

Tags: css, webpack, less

I'm using react day picker in react webpack. I dont want to use css file. So, how could i use a less a file instead of css file. I'm adding hash tag to the class names using webpack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to react-day-picker. To use Less instead of CSS you need to use the less-loader in your webpack config: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader